# COM registration error (80040154 Class not registered) using HTMLTextAreaElement in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am trying to insert text into a text area in a webpage using the following code:

```
Dim webTextArea As New HTMLTextAreaElement

WebTextArea = Main.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("name of web text area").DomElement
WebTextArea.value = "text to be inserted"
```

and receive the following error:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {3050F2AC-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B} failed due to the following error: `80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).`

Other information:
I'm using VB.Net in Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows 7 64 bit OS
Added "Imports mshtml"

I've tried referencing both the Microsoft HTML Object Library in the COM references tab and Microsoft.mshtml in the assembly tab.  I get the same error with either reference.

I am targeting the .NET 4.0 Framework and have set the target CPU to x86 (as suggested in responses to similar posts).

The Microsoft.mshtml.dll file exists in three locations on my hard drive:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Common
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies

All three files are version 7.0.3300.0

Two listings of Microsoft.mshtml show up in the referenced assemblies tab and I have tried selecting both individually.

When I remove references to both Microsoft HTML Object Library and the Microsoft.mshtml assembly I get a "Type 'HTMLTextAreaElement' is not defined" error when I try to compile.  This seems to indicate that each reference is being recognized.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tom, that you, I got it figured out

Answer (score 0):

GUID {3050F2AC-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B} is definitely from library MSHTML.

Google for MSHTML .Net.  You might find a few tips like this:

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/problem-net-2-0-and-mshtml-t2223192.html

Or better, try downloading and reinstalling MSHTML on your system:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=944